# Using delegate instead of building an association in Rails. What's the point?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking through some code and I see `delegate` and `has_many + through` being used instead of setting up an additional association. I was wondering what the benefit of using `delegate` is over setting up another `has_many` association.

```
class AppleCore
  belongs_to :apple
  delegate :tree to :apple
end
```

and then

```
class Apple
  belongs_to :tree
end
```

lastly

```
class Tree
  has_many :apples
end
```

In this example... why are we just delegating tree to apple and not creating an association between AppleCore and Tree?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because there is no direct link between AppleCore and Tree.
[This site might help clear things up.](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

It allows you make the code more readable. You can call `apple_core.tree` instead of `apple_core.apple.tree`. Where apple_core is an instance of AppleCore. If you set prefix to true, `delegate :tree to :apple, prefix: true`. You will access using `apple_core.apple_true`.

For more info checkout the [Rails Api Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate).